# VBA nested for loop - paste values

Tags: vba, loops, copy-paste

A simple question that I'm struggling with.

I am copying and pasting values from multiple worksheets into one master sheet, seen below.

```
Sub()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case LCase(ws.Name)
        Case [...] 'do nothing for selected worksheets
        Case Else
            ws.Range("J2") = ws.Name

            Dim myLastCell As Range
            Set myLastCell = LastCell(ws.Range("A:J"))

            ws.Range("A1:J" & myLastCell.Row).Copy Sheets("MasterDates").Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

The code above references a function myLastCell that finds the last cell.

**Here is the question:** I would also like to take that worksheet name that I put in each J2 and copy and paste it within each worksheet in every cell of a column, up until the data ends. That way, the appropriate dates would line up with all of the other values in the long master sheet that I'm creating.

I tried to insert the code below, both just the for loop itself and then within the sub, but I do not know how to incorporate this into the loop that's already happening. All help much appreciated!

```
Sub testpaste()
    DateValue = Range("J2").Value
    stoprow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 3 To stoprow
    Cells(i, 10).Value = DateValue
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the worksheet as an argument to your testpaste sub:

```
Sub testpaste(myWorksheet as worksheet)
    DateValue = myWorksheet.Range("J2").Value
    stoprow = myWorksheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 3 To stoprow
        myWorksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = DateValue
    Next
End Sub
```

Then call it from inside your Select statement with:

```
    Case Else
        ws.Range("J2") = ws.Name

        testpaste(ws)

        Dim myLastCell As Range
        Set myLastCell = LastCell(ws.Range("A:J"))

        ws.Range("A1:J" & myLastCell.Row).Copy Sheets("MasterDates").Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

But that would only really be necessary if you are intending to call it from other parts of your code. Otherwise you could just add it as part of the current Select statement:

```
    Case Else
        ws.Range("J2") = ws.Name

        DateValue = ws.Range("J2").Value
        stoprow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        For i = 3 To stoprow
            ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = DateValue
        Next

        Dim myLastCell As Range
        Set myLastCell = LastCell(ws.Range("A:J"))

        ws.Range("A1:J" & myLastCell.Row).Copy Sheets("MasterDates").Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```